# View password for connected wifi in chromebook

Tags: command-line, chromebook

I have a Chromebook at work and it is connected to a local network, but I cannot find the password in the details for the network like in windows(The security tab). Is there a command on crosh that is equivalent to windows' "netsh show profile [SSID] key=clear"? Or is there other ways to view the password?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible since you would have to be in Developer mode to see the password, but to get to developer mode, you have to Power Wash the machine, which will wipe the password.